# Elasticsearch: Mixing terms and ranges in post filter

Tags: post, elasticsearch, filter

I am trying to figure out how to apply multiple post_filters (like when a user selects multiple facets/aggregations)

```
  "post_filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {  "category": [ "Jewelry Collections", "Rings" ] }
        },
        {
          "terms": {  "size_jewelry": [ "6.5", "7"] }
        },        
        {
          "range": {  "price": [{ "gte": 0, "lte": 100  },{ "gte": 100, "lte": 200  }] }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

That obviously doesn't work. Basically, I'm trying to this:

category="Jewelry Collections" OR "Rings"
AND
size_jewelry="6.5" OR "7"
AND
price =0-100 OR price 100-200

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this will help.

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                            "terms": {
                                "category": ["Jewelry Collections", "Rings"]
                            }
                        }, {
                            "terms": {
                                "size_jewelry": ["6.5", "7"]
                            }
                        },
                        bool: {
                            should: [{
                                "range": {
                                    "price": {
                                        gte: 0,
                                        lte: 100
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "range": {
                                    "price": {
                                        gte: 100,
                                        lte: 200
                                    }
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks palash!  It does kind of help...but what I'm really after is how I can specify multiple price ranges in an "OR" fashion ("should" I guess is the correct term).

Comment: changed the query may be that should help, I dont think there is multiple range support in ranges so you should use "should" for implying OR filters

Comment: .Hi midget,If that helped can you please upvote and accept the answer, I need it to ask my questions thanks.

Comment: I tried to upvote but I am too new - I don't have enough "reputation" :( But I accepted the answer.  I really appreciate it!